# What is "Waiting for eb2.3lift.com...."?

Tags: malware, vpn, virus, spyware

I am using [purevpn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PureVPN) on Firefox, I have noticed that when I open the browser sometimes it hangs and on the bottom left hand corner it says "Waiting for eb2.3lift.com..."

I tried to google this eb2.3lift.com but don't seem to find any answers. Does anyone know is it malware /virus related?

P.S. I have AVG free version installed, I did a system scan & found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the API servers for the advertising network triplelift.com. Most likely, they are benign, but they are also useless for whatever you're trying to view. Most ad blocking extensions should block their cookies and advertisements automatically.